# SAML Bearer Assertion Issuer/ClientId

Tags: oauth2, saml

In the [OAuth 2.0 SAML Bearer Assertion Flow for Previously Authorized Apps](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_SAML_bearer_flow.htm&type=5), what is the issuer supposed to be?

I am trying to connect to orgs that have single sign on working. I have followed [this example code](https://github.com/salesforceidentity/apex-saml-bearer-flow/blob/master/SAMLBearerAssertion.apex.txt).

Using the issuer as the issuer from the connected app - e.g. https://mydomain.my.salesforce.com - leads to this error:
`{"error":"invalid_client_id","error_description":"client identifier invalid"}`
with a corresponding error in the login history of the org I am trying to connect to `(Failed: Missing Consumer Key Parameter)`

Comment: Issuer is the connected app's client id (aka consumer key) - the doc you reference does say this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the same [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_SAML_bearer_flow.htm&type=5), Issuer is the value of the connected app’s OAuth client_id for which the developer registered their certificate.

Issuer refers to the Entity Id of your identity provider, it is a URL that uniquely identifies your SAML identity provider. SAML assertions sent to Salesforce must match this value exactly in the attribute of SAML assertions.